# On Windows (x86), how is the PFN database indexed?

Tags: windows, virtual-memory, x86

*Windows Internals* has a section on virtual memory. I understand that the PFN fields in L4 entries, PDPEs, and PDEs refer to the base address of the next level tables, and that the PTE's PFN refers to the location of the page in memory (after shifting).

I also understand that the Windows' PFN database contains additional information about every page. It appears to be indexed by the PTE's PFN. That would mean one should exist per PDE. Is that true? How is it located?

Perhaps it's in the book but then I must be overlooking it.

Comment: What book are you talking about?

Comment: _Windows Internals, Part 1_, 7th ed.: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2017/05/09/new-book-windows-internals-seventh-edition-part-1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PFN database is at high-canonical virtual address `0xFFFFFA8000000000`. It can be a maximum virtual size `0x57FFFFFFFFF` (6TiB) (`0x1D5555556` entries of size `0x30` bytes each). This covers 512 TiB (49 bits) even though only 256TiB physical space is typically allowed on [64 bit Intel chipsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#hronology) (restricted by <=48 bit PTE address fields -- remember virtual addresses are always 48 bits on PML4 x64 windows) (`0x1D5555556*PageSize = 512TiB`). On my machine the PFN Database appears to be from `0xFFFFFA8000000000 – FFFFFA80197EC000`, the latter address being `nt!MmNonPagedPoolStart-1`. PFN 0 corresponds to the first physical frame at PA `0x0000`; PFN 1 corresponds to the 2nd physical frame at `0x1000` and so on.

> To find the size of the PFN database the expression `? poi(nt!MmNonPagedPoolStart) - poi(nt!MmPfnDatabase)` can be used in the debugger. And to find the total number of entries in the PFN database the expression can be used `?(poi(nt!MmNonPagedPoolStart) - poi(nt!MmPfnDatabase))/ @@(sizeof(nt!_MMPFN))` [[1]](http://To%20find%20the%20size%20of%20the%20PFN%20database%20the%20expression%20%27?%20poi(nt!MmNonPagedPoolStart)%20-%20poi(nt!MmPfnDatabase)%27%20can%20be%20used%20in%20the%20debugger.%20And%20to%20find%20the%20total%20number%20of%20entries%20in%20the%20PFN%20database%20the%20expression%20can%20be%20used%20%27?(poi(nt!MmNonPagedPoolStart)%20-%20poi(nt!MmPfnDatabase))/%20@@(sizeof(nt!_MMPFN))%27.%20nt!MmPfnDatabase%20defines%20the%20start%20of%20this%20region.)

Use the PFN number (high 36 bits of the 48 bit physical address) to index into the PFN (times it by 0x30 entry size) to get the `nt!_MMPFN` that describes that physical frame.

MMPFN format:

[image]

Certain MMPFNs will be on certain lists (zero, free, standby, modified) connected by the forward and backward links connecting them to another MMPFN that is connected on the list.

Type: The type of page represented by this PFN. (Types include active/valid, standby, modified, modified-no-write, free, zeroed, bad, and transition.)

Colour: Besides being linked together on a list, PFN database entries use an additional field to link physical frame by “colour,” which is the page’s NUMA node number.

PFN of PTE aka. 'containing page': the physical frame number of the page containing the PTE that points to this physical frame: !pfn containing page

PTE address is the virtual address of the PTE structure that points to the page (kernel memory VA that is mapped to all processes). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972057/windows-10-x64-unable-to-get-pxe-on-windbg/66751725#66751725) for how to get virtual address of PTE, PDE, PDPTE and PML4E for a virtual address. To get the virtual address that this PTE covers, you need to reverse the equation in the link above, so
`#define MiPteToAddress(x) ((PVOID)((ULONG)(x) << 10))`. The two low-order
bits of this member are used as a locking mechanism to serialize access to the PFN entry.

Original PTE contents – `MiModifiedPageWriter` writes out modified pages on the modified list to the pagefile (which have been `invlpg`d <sup>[1]</sup>, invalidated and turned into transition PTEs and their PFN entries have been added to the modified list (if they are modified, otherwise to standby list) by the working set manager) and replaces their PTEs with software PTEs which contain the address of the page in the pagefile and adds the PFNs to the tail of the standby list. It also has to modify the PTE and convert it to a page file software PTE which contains the page file address that the page was written to. I think it does this by using the PFN of PTE to calculate the physical address of the PTE, which it maps in to the hyperspace in order to modify it if it isn't a kernel virtual address (it also has to read and set PDE/PDPTE/PML4E Access/Dirty bits for the process if they aren't already set seeing as the TLB will be using the system context and not the context of the process when it writes A/D bits). `MiMappedPageWriter` is what instead writes modified file-mapped pages back to their files or indeed file-mapped CoW written pages to the page file. From what I can see, this original / restore PTE contains the page file software PTE in some scenarios and the PPTE in other scenarios. This might provide this particular page of data with a permanent pagefile address such that when it is written out again, it is written to the same address, and can be used to write back pages in one contiguous I/O request. The PFN field may also allow for this pagefile address to be copied into the PTE only when the page moves from the standby to the zeroed list so that while it is on the standby list the PTE can still be a standby fault and the page can be satisfied from RAM, although [this](https://community.osr.com/discussion/237640) shows the PTE becomes a pagefile invalid type while the PFN is still modified write in progress.

The reference count is incremented when a page is first added to a working set and/or when the page is locked in memory for I/O (for example, by a device driver). The reference count is decremented when the share count becomes 0 or when pages are unlocked from memory. When the share count becomes 0, the page is no longer owned by a working set. Then, if the reference count is also zero, the PFN database entry that describes the page is updated to add the page to the free, standby, or modified list.

The share count field represents the number of PTEs that refer to this page (as pages marked read-only, copy-on-write, or shared read/write can be shared by multiple processes).

If the frame is part of the working set of the process then it will have a working set index which is the index into the array of MMWSLEs of the process. The array is pointed to by the MMWSL structure which is pointed to by the MMSUPPORT structure which is pointed to by the EPROCESS structure.

The caching attributes state whether the page is cacheable or not, or write combining etc. The flags indicate stuff like whether the page is for a kernel stack, whether the page is in the process of being paged in or out, whether there was an error in that process 'in-page error' etc. The type aka. pagelocation states what type the physical frame is (active, standby, modified etc.)

<sup>[1]</sup> It would have to invalidate other cores with IPIs by interrupting them to an interrupt vector that flushes and invalidates their TLBs (known as TLB shootdown) like `INVALIDATE_TLB_VECTOR` on linux, which appears to be implemented using a mov to cr3 and the core that sends the IPI to allbutself spinwaits on a bitmask (`smp_invalidate_needed` on linux) of completed TLB clears (which is necessary because the CPU being interrupted could be performing a large MSROM routine which might write to that page, and interrupts can only be handled at the end of a macroinstruction retirement), so that any cores that might be executing in that process's context do not write or read from the new page while itis being written out and instead quickly incur a page fault the next time they perform a page walk. The same occurs for the modified page writer, but those page faults on other cores will not be able to be handled as the page writer acquired the PFN entry lock so it could write an in-page-write-in-progress bit in the PFN entry before it sent the IPIs, and those threads will wait on the mutex event specified in the PFN. It needs to acquire the lock and set the in progress bit before modifying the PTE and performing the TLB shootdown so that it is an atomic process i.e. so that a page fault for the same page doesn't see a page file PTE and a free PFN entry and initiate a disk read for a page that hasn't been written yet.

This is my guess based on the manuals and general axioms. I haven't verified by looking at the ReactOS source code of the memory manager yet.